# Restricting Office 365 Users from sharing folders to external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

From the Admin Portal, how can one restrict Office 365 users from sharing specific folders on Team Sites to external users.

Comment: You could use permissions to restrict access to a folder. However if the information in the folder/library should not be available to the public you should probably review the permissions settings for the site and not allow anonymous access.

Comment: So you cannot make permissions to the folders not to be shared externally?

Comment: I don't know what you have done so far. but by default unauthenticated users do not have access to anything. For the Authenticated users you should use groups, for a more granular access to specific resources on the site. i think you should read up on SharePoint permission model and how to manage it, here is a link fo ryou to get started. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/help/permissions-in-office-365-HA104043996.aspx

Comment: Do you want the ability to share to external users on other folders/items?  If not, simply disable the feature in the SharePoint Admin center.  Otherwise you'll need to provide some more information.  Are these folders all on the same site?  Do you want users to be able to share anything else on that site to external users?

Comment: If that's the case, then I will just have to create a site that I can make the folders be public. Thanks @wjervis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to restrict external sharing of folders, since this is controlled on the site collection level in the SharePoint Admin Center. Either you allow external sharing on the entire site collection, or you don’t.

Reference: [Restricting Office 365 Users from sharing folders to external users](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/278079.aspx)

Comment: If that's the case, then I will just have to create a site that I can make the folders be public. Thanks @Benny-Skogberg